# Export Excel file data to Datatable

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, excel-2010

I was wondering if there is a recommended way to import data of an Excel file (.xlsx) to a Datatable using VB.NET but without knowing the structure of the Excel file. In other words a user will download an Excel file in which there is no consistency. The header may start at C1 instead of A1. Anything could be anywhere and the Excel file will not follow a specific structure. All examples I found on the Internet seem to presume that the Excel file has no spaces, no merges and all data is evenly divided amongst rows and columns.

Any recommendations for any possible libraries that will loop through the whole Excel file, get the text and stick it into a Datatable?

I am using SQL and that side of things is OK as it’s been tested.

Comment: Hello there! Welcome to stack overflow. I see you are a newbie here. Please spare 5 minutes of your valuable time to take [this tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to figure out how things work around here..

Comment: Thanks for the guidance

Comment: Think about how you would respond to to being asked to write down the steps to manually perform the task of creating a table of data given the constraint "Anything could be anywhere and the Excel file will not follow a specific structure" and you will have a basis for a question.  If you can accomplish this task, edit your question to include this procedure and then we can begin discussing a programming solution.

Comment: That’s the truth. Anything can be anywhere. I’m not sure exactly how you want me to decorate that. That’s the question, if it really cannot be answered it can be closed and deleted.

Comment: It would probably be easier to get the senders to fill in a specific form :-)

Comment: Impossible. I can’t believe I can’t find anything on the net about this, well not anything I can understand anyway. Simply put I have three columns with headers that start at F12,G12 and J12 of the Excel worksheet. To those three columns I want to add another two empty columns into the datatable. I want my datatable to have 5 columns. It looks like I’m asking for too much based on what I’m finding on the web.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just do a `select *`, as such?

```
Imports System.Data
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
                ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Try
            Dim MyConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection
            Dim DtSet As System.Data.DataSet
            Dim MyCommand As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
            MyConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection _
            ("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"  _
            " Data Source='c:\testfile.xls'; " _
             "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
            MyCommand = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter _
                ("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection)
            MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Table", "TestTable")
            DtSet = New System.Data.DataSet
            MyCommand.Fill(DtSet)
            DataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables(0)
            MyConnection.Close()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```